# Can I claim lost income if a company I invested in went out of business?

Tags: taxes, canada, income, capital-gains-tax

What happens when a company I invested in goes out of business?  Is that declared as a personal capital loss?  Does it offset capital gains elsewhere, and how do I include it in my tax filing?

Answer (score 4):

If this was a public corporation (stock) and the investment was made in a non-registered account, then you can claim a capital loss.  Capital losses are claimed against capital gains (not income), and can be carried back 3 years or carried forward indefinitely.

Here's an article I've written on [how to claim capital losses](http://www.milliondollarjourney.com/reduce-your-taxes-by-claiming-calculatin-your-capital-loss.htm) that may help.

Answer (score 2):

Since you say the money was invested in a corporation that would lead me to believe you mean a stock purchase. Stock losses can be treated as a tax exemption filed as a capital loss.

http://moneycentral.msn.com/content/Taxes/Cutyourtaxes/P33438.asp

http://www.usatoday.com/money/perfi/columnist/krantz/2006-03-10-capital-losses_x.htm

Canada has slightly more restrictions on how this can be done.

http://www.taxtips.ca/filing/capitallosses.htm